# Compressing the Page Cache

Tags: full-page-cache, gzip, local-storage

My Full Page Cache Currently takes ~1 GB Space. My total allotment of the disk is 7 GB. The performance and everything are great, however, I am concerned about disk space. I am using 80% of disk space right now. Is there a possibility to compress the full page cache? as most of it is text, I can save a lot with GZIP compression.